# Efficient low-rank appoximation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I'd like to compute a low-rank approximation to a matrix which is optimal under the Frobenius norm. The trivial way to do this is to compute the SVD decomposition of the matrix, set the smallest singular values to zero and compute the low-rank matrix by multiplying the factors. Is there a simple and more efficient way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: What do you mean by "simple", "efficient"?

Comment: by simple I mean that a reference to a 30 page research paper whose implementation requires writing 500 lines of code is not the answer I'm looking for.  By efficient I mean that I'd like to improve the runtime over the trivial approach.

Comment: I doubt that there is a trivial answer.. After all, if it were, why would Mathworks "forget" about it?

Comment: By any chance, is your matrix "symmetric definite positive"?

Comment: Can you describe why the SVD method you outlined is not good enough? Are you working with very large matrices or many matrices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your matrix is sparse, use `svds`.

Assuming it is not sparse but it's large, you can use random projections for fast low-rank approximation.

From a [tutorial](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/el327/papers/RandomProjectionsSeminar.pdf):

> An optimal low rank approximation can be easily computed using the SVD of *A* in *O(mn^2
>   )*. Using random projections we show how to achieve an ”almost optimal” low rank pproximation in *O(mn log(n))*.

Matlab code from a [blog](http://nuit-blanche.blogspot.com/2007/11/monday-morning-algorithm-part-1-fast.html):

```
clear
% preparing the problem
% trying to find a low approximation to A, an m x n matrix
% where m >= n
m = 1000;
n = 900;
%// first let's produce example A
A = rand(m,n);
%
% beginning of the algorithm designed to find alow rank matrix of A
% let us define that rank to be equal to k
k = 50;
% R is an m x l matrix drawn from a N(0,1)
% where l is such that l > c log(n)/ epsilon^2
%
l = 100;
% timing the random algorithm
trand =cputime;
R = randn(m,l);
B = 1/sqrt(l)* R' * A;
[a,s,b]=svd(B);
Ak = A*b(:,1:k)*b(:,1:k)';
trandend = cputime-trand;
% now timing the normal SVD algorithm
tsvd = cputime;
% doing it the normal SVD way
[U,S,V] = svd(A,0);
Aksvd= U(1:m,1:k)*S(1:k,1:k)*V(1:n,1:k)';
tsvdend = cputime -tsvd;
```

Also, remember the `econ` parameter of `svd`.

Comment: Is this an exact method or an approximation? Is it numerically backward-stable?

Comment: I've done some benchmarking and the function svds can be (significantly) faster than svd for dense matrices as well, for a low enough rank. If you'll include that in the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You can post and accept your own answer regarding `svds` for a dense matrix. Note that Matlab documentation states:"`d = eigs(A,k)` is not a substitute for `d = eig(full(A)); d = sort(d); d = d(end-k+1:end);` but is most appropriate for large sparse matrices. If the problem fits into memory, it may be quicker to use `eig(full(A))`."  `eigs` is called by `svds`.

Answer (score 5):

You can rapidly compute a low-rank approximation based on SVD, using the `svds` function.

```
[U,S,V] = svds(A,r); %# only first r singular values are computed
```

`svds` uses `eigs` to compute a subset of the singular values - it will be especially fast for large, sparse matrices. See the documentation; you can set tolerance and maximum number of iterations or choose to calculate small singular values instead of large.

I thought `svds` and `eigs` could be faster than `svd` and `eig` for dense matrices, but then I did some benchmarking.  They are only faster for large matrices when sufficiently few values are requested:

```
 n     k       svds          svd         eigs          eig            comment
10     1     4.6941e-03   8.8188e-05   2.8311e-03   7.1699e-05    random matrices
100    1     8.9591e-03   7.5931e-03   4.7711e-03   1.5964e-02     (uniform dist)
1000   1     3.6464e-01   1.8024e+00   3.9019e-02   3.4057e+00
       2     1.7184e+00   1.8302e+00   2.3294e+00   3.4592e+00
       3     1.4665e+00   1.8429e+00   2.3943e+00   3.5064e+00
       4     1.5920e+00   1.8208e+00   1.0100e+00   3.4189e+00
4000   1     7.5255e+00   8.5846e+01   5.1709e-01   1.2287e+02
       2     3.8368e+01   8.6006e+01   1.0966e+02   1.2243e+02
       3     4.1639e+01   8.4399e+01   6.0963e+01   1.2297e+02
       4     4.2523e+01   8.4211e+01   8.3964e+01   1.2251e+02


10     1      4.4501e-03   1.2028e-04   2.8001e-03   8.0108e-05   random pos. def.
100    1      3.0927e-02   7.1261e-03   1.7364e-02   1.2342e-02    (uniform dist)
1000   1      3.3647e+00   1.8096e+00   4.5111e-01   3.2644e+00
       2      4.2939e+00   1.8379e+00   2.6098e+00   3.4405e+00
       3      4.3249e+00   1.8245e+00   6.9845e-01   3.7606e+00
       4      3.1962e+00   1.9782e+00   7.8082e-01   3.3626e+00
4000   1      1.4272e+02   8.5545e+01   1.1795e+01   1.4214e+02
       2      1.7096e+02   8.4905e+01   1.0411e+02   1.4322e+02
       3      2.7061e+02   8.5045e+01   4.6654e+01   1.4283e+02
       4      1.7161e+02   8.5358e+01   3.0066e+01   1.4262e+02
```

With size-`n` square matrices, `k` singular/eigen values and runtimes in seconds.  I used Steve Eddins' `timeit` file exchange function for benchmarking, which tries to account for overhead and runtime variations.

`svds` and `eigs` are faster if you want a few values from a very large matrix.  It also depends on the properties of the matrix in question (`edit svds` should give you some idea why).

Comment: Interesting to hear that `svds` works faster than `svd` for some dense matrices when searching for the first singular values. Is it because 500x100 is not large enough?

Comment: The larger the matrix, the faster `svds` and `eigs` *can* be. I had to eat my words a little - see my latest edit above.