# do singular value decomposition in Matlab

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficient low-rank appoximation in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791537/efficient-low-rank-appoximation-in-matlab)

I am trying to do SVD for a matrix of size 7468 x 1193 in matlab. Surprisingly enough, it takes a very long time -- I would think that this is a relatively small matrix for Matlab / SVD. Is there a better implementation for SVD in matlab which can tackle this size of matrices? I don't really need *all* singular vectors from U and V, but relatively a small number of them (say 50 or so).

Comment: i have matrix 5383x6236 and i am using Math.Extreme code thorowing  outofMemoryException can i do this in matlab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible in matlab, using `svds` (with a `s` at the end):

```
k=50;
[U,S,V]=svds(A,k);
```

Comment: i have matrix 5383x6236 and i am using Math.Extreme code thorowing outofMemoryException can i do this in matlab?

Comment: What is "Math.Extreme" ? Anyway, if it throws outofMemoryException, I guess you should buy more RAM or use smaller matrices.

Comment: Math.Extreme is .net libruary

Comment: This question is about the matlab language not .net